# rabbitmq c# alter policy of vhost

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm wondering what the best way to alter the policy of a vhost is within the C# driver.  I know I can post the following to the API:

url: `http://localhost:15672/api/policies/vhost123/DLX`

body:

```
{
    "pattern":".*", 
    "definition": {
        "dead-letter-exchange":"DLX123"
    }, 
    "priority":0, 
    "apply-to": "all"
}
```

Is there any way to do this within the C# driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this through the C# interface but you can do it directly with a call to the API.  Here is my solution:

```
    internal static void DeleteDLXPolicyOnVhost()
    {
        const string policyURL = "http://localhost:15672/api/policies/vhost123/DLX";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username123:password123");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            var response = client.DeleteAsync(policyURL).Result;
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.NoContent:
                    Console.WriteLine("Old DLX policy successfully deleted");
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    Console.WriteLine("DLX policy was not found");
                    break;
                default:
                {
                    var content = response.Content;
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unhandled API response code of {0}, content: {1}", response.StatusCode, content));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```